# Are there any obvious inefficiencies in my code? [Square Sums Hamiltonian Path Recursive ]

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, math, path

I am attempting to solve the Square Sums problem found at https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a667236145c462103000091/train/python.

Write function that, given an integer number N, returns array of integers 1..N arranged in a way, so sum of each 2 consecutive numbers is a square. The solution is valid if and only if following two criterias are met:

1. Each number in the range 1..N is used once and only once.
2. The sum of each 2 consecutive numbers is a perfect square.

I need advice on how to optimize my current solution. After running some tests, I have found that the most time-consuming part of my code is the creation of the new dict each time:

```
else:
        possible_nodes  ={key: list(set(values) - {first_one}) for key, values in possible_nodes.items()
```

}

However, I am not sure how to change it. Currently, I can solve for N=1000 in approximately 0.7 seconds, but I would need to make it 10 times faster. If anyone has tips or suggestions for improvement, I would be grateful for your input.

```
def square_sums(N):
    def inner(N, done_already=[], filterr=False, possible_nodes={}, options={}, first_one=0):
        if len(done_already) == N - 1:
            left_over = [x for x in range(1, N+1) if x not in done_already][0]
            if (left_over + done_already[-1]) in options:
                done_already.append(left_over)
                return done_already
            else:
                return False
        if not filterr:
            options = {n**2 for n in range(1, int((2*N-1)**0.5) + 1)}
            for pie in range(1, N+1):
                if pie not in done_already:
                    possible_nodes[pie] = [x for x in range(1, N+1) if x+pie in options and x!=pie and x not in done_already]
        else:
            possible_nodes  ={key: list(set(values) - {first_one}) for key, values in possible_nodes.items()}
            possible_nodes.pop(first_one)
            if set() in possible_nodes.values():
                return False
        if not filterr:
            short = min([len(cc) for cc in possible_nodes.values()])
            next_up = [x for x, y in possible_nodes.items() if len(y)==short]
        else:
            grind= [xx for xx in possible_nodes.keys() if (xx+done_already[-1]) in options]
            try:
                short = min([len(cc) for kk, cc in possible_nodes.items() if kk in grind])
                next_up = [x for x,y in possible_nodes.items() if len(y)==short and x in grind]
            except ValueError:
                return False
    
        for possible_path in next_up:
            done_already.append(possible_path)
            if inner(N, done_already, True, possible_nodes, options, possible_path):
                return done_already
            else:
                done_already.pop()
        return False
    return inner(N)
```

Comment: Given that your code works and you want help to improve it, this question might be a better fit on [codereview.se]

Comment: `if set() in possible_nodes.values()` it's never there, you convert to `list` all values two lines before this check.

Comment: Can you avoid ever converting to list, and then replace your "slow" line (which discards the current `possible_nodes` and constructs a new one) with an in-place modification like `for v in possible_nodes.values(): v -= {first_one}` ?

Comment: And your code fails the test for `N=23` given in the task...

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike it doesn't fail for any of the tests, I just edited the version I put here slightly to make it more readable. It passes all tests but times out. Basically you can't have default variables in the function in the codewars test so I had to nest it

Comment: I just copied your code from question to the sandbox, clicked "Test", and got `TypeError: Solution must be a list!` for `n=23`. And `Passed: 3 Failed: 102+` with "Attempt" button (errors start with `fA solution exists for 23!`).

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike I have edited the code now, it should work (or at least the code here passes all the tests it does within the time limit on codewars). Thanks for your help

Comment: @slothrop thanks for that suggestion, ~I implemented a variation of it and it is about 4x faster when it does work but now am getting other errors related to my .pop(first_one) line but I will try and figure it out, your suggestion has definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

We can treat this as a graph with integers for nodes, and edges between pairs of integers that sum to a square. Then, the paths which visits all vertices exactly once (Hamiltonian paths) are the solutions (if any).

One possible approach is described by Andreas Björklund in his paper: AN ASYMPTOTICALLY FAST POLYNOMIAL SPACE ALGORITHM FOR HAMILTONICITY DETECTION IN SPARSE DIRECTED GRAPHS (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.11780.pdf).

For average outdegree delta, this detects the cycle in O(2^[n - omega(n / delta)]) time.

To use this we need to treat each edge as a pair of arcs.

Another approach, for undirected graphs: A Simple Algorithm for Undirected Hamiltonicity, by Abasi and Bshouty. https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2013/012/download/

Answer (score -1):

I suggest following easy-to-apply amelorations

```
min([len(cc) for cc in possible_nodes.values()])
min([len(cc) for kk, cc in possible_nodes.items() if kk in grind])
```

built-in `min` function can take `list`s but it is not limited to them, you might use comprehension with `min` without building `list` that is that doing e.g.

```
min(i**2 for i in somelist)
```

rather than

```
min([i**2 for i in somelist])
```

Appending to list *may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container.* according to [wiki.python.org](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), you might use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) as drop-in replacement (it is part of standard library)

```
[x for x in range(1, N+1) if x not in done_already][0]
```

You are building whole list in order to just get 1st element, you might avoid that following way

```
next(filter(lambda x:x not in done_already,range(1, N+1))
```

note that this will give result dependant on position of first `not in done_already` element to length or range ratio.

Comment: If you don't like `filter`, use generator expression instead of listcomp: `next(x for x in range(1, N+1) if x not in done_already)` is equivalent. (And AFAIC `filter+lambda` was a bit slower than generator due to function overhead, there are SO questions regarding this).

Comment: I rather doubt the first half of the answer, in my experience list comps are *faster* than genexps (unless the list is very large, causing cache/memory issues). Please demonstrate that your suggestion is indeed better here.

Comment: The deque suggestion is equally doubtful, list is probably faster.

Comment: The last advice, only searching until the not done value, is somewhat good, but you implemented it in such a slow way that I'm not convinced it's an actual improvement.